# Normality of free product

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

For simplicity, let's consider product of two groups.

Let $G,H$ be groups.

Define $\overline{G}=G\times\{e\}$ and $\overline{H}=\{e\}\times H$.

Then, $\overline{G}$ and $\overline{H}$ are normal subgroups of the direct product $G\times H$.

I wonder if the above property or similar to that holds in free product too.

To be precise, let $\pi_G:G\rightarrow G\ast H$ and $\pi_H:H\rightarrow G\ast H$ be the embeddings.

Then, are $\pi_G(G)$ and $\pi_H(H)$ normal in $G\ast H$? Moreover, are they characteristic in $G\ast H$?

Comment: No, they are never normal in the free product when they are both non-trivial.

Comment: @GeoffRobinson I cannot really see why. Would you please explain to me how they look like in the product?

Comment: Take a look at the general theory in Serre's book "Trees", for example. Any expression of the form $x_{1}y_{1}x_{2}y_{2} \ldots x_{n}$ with all $x_{i}$ non-identity elements of $H$ and all $y_{i}$ non-identity elements of $G$ lies outside $G \cup H$. In particular, $h^{-1}gh$ lies outside $G$ for $g$ a non-identity element of $G$ and $h$ a non-identity element of $H$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose $g\in G$ and $h\in H$ are nonidentity elements. Then the conjugate $hgh^{-1}$ is not an element of the subgroup of $G\ast H$ corresponding to $G$. Thus this subgroup is not normal.